# How to load gif image in ionic app - Android/IOS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Am facing a issue with ionic. here, how to load gif image in `<image src="icon.gif">` in a html page.
its working in browser but not in mobile or device.
can any one help me.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: any solution here? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You only need to put the following HTML tag with the complete URL of your GIF image:

```
<img ng-src="{{yourGifURL}}" alt="Description" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you using the file name as case sensitive like 'loading.gif' or 'Loading.gif'.
And also use the `<img src="">`
I was having a similar issue.